# What is the best tool for doing explorative analysis of databases?

Tags: tool-request, sql

We are looking for a tool that plugs into a database (SQL) and help us query and visualize results dynamically, building monitoring dashboards and dynamic queries.

Any good tool out there?

Comment: It's not cheap, but Tableau does all those things out of the box. You can use Tableau Public for free, but then your data is really "open".

Comment: Also, I think if you expand your question, it might get more specific answers. Are you commercial or non-commericial, looking for open source, free, paid, etc?

Comment: Agree with philshem, can you expend also on the level of coding you are willing to invest (ie. are you looking for a ready to use tool or visualization libraries?)

Answer (score 4):

looks like possibly same question on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835572/how-to-use-pure-sql-for-exploratory-data-analysis

most results i found recommend using R
http://www.renzeconsulting.com/presentations/exploratory-data-analysis-with-r.pdf

looks like these two solutions cost:
http://science.nature.nps.gov/im/units/arcn/documents/documents/nps-arcn-dmsop-2009-03_exploratory_data_analysis_using_sqlserverstudio_v1.0_20090210.pdf

http://spie.org/Publications/Proceedings/Paper/10.1117/12.907097